# I Need To Display A Specific Product (Called By Meta Field) On It's Current WooCommerce Category Page

Tags: plugins

I am trying to build a little module onto the product-archive template for WooCommerce that will accomplish one goal.

I have included custom meta fields on the category editor page so that I can paste in specific product SKUs on that page to have as Featured Products.  However, I need to figure out a way to have WooCommerce query the current category of products and list the product that has the same SKU that I have listed in the category meta.

in other words...

Product Category -> Custom Meta Field (Product Sku) -> On Product Category Page, Display Product With Matching SKU from current category.

Is something like this even possible?  I have been wracking my brain for hours trying to get this to work.  Honestly, it doesn't seem like that crazy of an idea, but there is just nothing available that I can with a bit of guidance in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce uses Custom Post Types for its products and as such uses standard WP_Query to return results on those pages. You can probably use the `pre_get_posts()` to modify the query on certain pages or archives.

[WordPress Codex Page for `pre_get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)